# Как сделать footer посередине?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, bootstrap

Добавил в Footer класс navbar-fixed-bottom и Fotter прижался, но растянулся на всю. Как сделать его таким же как и остальной контент по центру (выделил красным)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3):

Как вариант:

```
<div class="navbar-fixed-bottom">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar navbar-default">
            содержимое футера.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Самые распространённые для меня, это два позиционирования по центру. Может вам что-то подойдёт. Ещё есть третий через абсолют, но его в основном использую только для модальных окон.

1. Через классический margin: 0 auto

```css
.footer {
  max-width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<footer class='footer'/>
```

2. Через flex ==> justify-content: center

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.footer {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <footer class="footer" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Поместите footer в контейнер с ограниченной шириной и будет вам счастье.